Crash | Can't access Looper on Coroutines Dispatchers.IO
I'm executing some tasks on Coroutines Dispatchers.IO like this to achieve concurrency:
fun postMessage(request: Request) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val requestHandler = getRequestHandler(request)
        requestHandler.handleRequest()
    }
}

These tasks individually can call other methods or classes which use Handler or Toast and they require looper. Looper is not present in Dispatchers.IO. They can also perform UI related tasks and other background tasks. This is not the issue, for UI related tasks, I can simply launch a coroutine in using Dispatchers.Main.
Here's a sample trace:
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.mywebapp.app, PID: 14902
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()

I also tried executing these tasks on a HandlerThread then these tasks will be executed "sequentially" on that thread.
I have also tried creating an HandlerThread:
class MyDispatcher {
    val handlerThread = HandlerThread("myThread").apply {
        start()
    }
    val handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
    val coroutineDispatcher = handler.asCoroutineDispatcher()
}

and then launching a coroutine like this:
val dispatcher = MyDispatcher()
CoroutineScope(dispatcher.coroutineDispatcher).launch {
    //....
}

However, this will execute all my tasks in a sequential manner on the "myThread".
I want to achieve true concurrency here that Dispatchers.IO provide us.
So how do i solve this?

You're essentially constrained by implementation of those tasks and their need of being executed with a looper. I don't think you can solve it in a nice manner other than spawning multiple handler threads but managing/reusing them is a headache.
